# How to render a custom template for a collection in Zend2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

in form:

```
$this->add(array(
        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Collection',
        'name' => 'openHours',
        'options' => array(
            'label' => 'Hours',
            'count' => 2,
            'should_create_template' => true,
            'template_placeholder' => '__placeholder__',
            'target_element' => array(
                'type' => 'Listings\Form\OpenHourFieldset',
            ),
        ),
    ));
```

in form.phtml

```
<?php $openHoursCollection = $form->get('openHours'); ?>
    <?php foreach ($openHoursCollection as $collection){ ?>
        <fieldset>
            <?php echo $this->formSelect($collection->get('weekday')); ?>
        </fieldset>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php echo $this->formCollection->renderTemplate($openHoursCollection); ?>
```

When iterating through collection items in zend2 for it to work properly it would also need a custom template.  but how to get `$this->formCollection->renderTemplate($collection)` 
to render a custom HTML?
I need all this collection rendering to be custom

Any one knows ?
thanks

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this is best approach but I've solved this problem by creating my own view helper to render and template to add items dynamically in JavaSrcript in browser.

Create view helper extending standard form collection view helper:

```
<?php

namespace App\View\Helper;

use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormCollection;
use Zend\Form\ElementInterface;
use Zend\Form\Element\Collection as CollectionElement;
use Zend\Form\FieldsetInterface;

class ItemListFormCollection extends FormCollection
{
    private $elementformat =
            '<div class="form-group input-group input-group-sm">%s
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default delete" type="button">Delete</button>
                </span>
            </div>';

    public function __invoke(ElementInterface $element = null, $wrap = true)
    {
        if(!$element){
            return $this;
        }
        $this->setShouldWrap($wrap);
        return $this->render($element);
    }

    public function render(ElementInterface $element)
    {
        $renderer = $this->getView();
        if (!method_exists($renderer, 'plugin')) {
            return '';
        }

        $markup           = '';
        $templateMarkup   = '';
        $escapeHtmlHelper = $this->getEscapeHtmlHelper();
        $elementHelper    = $this->getElementHelper();
        $fieldsetHelper   = $this->getFieldsetHelper();

        if ($element instanceof CollectionElement && $element->shouldCreateTemplate()) {
            $templateMarkup = $this->renderTemplate($element);
        }

        foreach ($element->getIterator() as $elementOrFieldset) {
            if ($elementOrFieldset instanceof FieldsetInterface) {
                $markup .= sprintf($this->elementformat,$fieldsetHelper($elementOrFieldset));
            } elseif ($elementOrFieldset instanceof ElementInterface) {
                $markup .= $elementHelper($elementOrFieldset);
            }
        }

        if (!empty($templateMarkup)) {
            $markup .= $templateMarkup;
        }

        return $markup;
    }

    public function renderTemplate(CollectionElement $collection)
    {
        $elementHelper          = $this->getElementHelper();
        $escapeHtmlAttribHelper = $this->getEscapeHtmlAttrHelper();
        $templateMarkup         = '';

        $elementOrFieldset = $collection->getTemplateElement();

        if ($elementOrFieldset instanceof FieldsetInterface) {
            $templateMarkup .= $this->render($elementOrFieldset);
        } elseif ($elementOrFieldset instanceof ElementInterface) {
            $templateMarkup .= $elementHelper($elementOrFieldset);
        }

        $element = sprintf($this->elementformat, $templateMarkup);

        return sprintf(
            '<span data-template="%s"></span>',
            $escapeHtmlAttribHelper($element)
        );
    }
}
```

You can modify `$elementformat` variable to your own format.

Next You should register this helper in view helper service manager in config/module.config.php:

```
...
'view_helpers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'itemListFormCollection' => 'App\View\Helper\ItemListFormCollection'
    )
),
...
```

And now you can use it as original formCollection helper in any view file:

```
<?php echo $this->itemListFormCollection($form->get('collection')); ?>
```

Comment: Can see that its not quite straight forward .. anyway its better than nothing. I'll give it a try and will come back with updates. Cheers